# Необходимо составить regexp который будет соответствовать в случае, если указаны все цифры в любом порядке

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Одна цифра может присутствовать несколько раз, порядок цифр неважен.

true - если есть все цифры хотя бы в одном экземпляре, в любом порядке.

*Примеры:*

0123456789 **true**

1023456789 **true**

10234567893251 **true**

1123456789 **false** (нет 0)

0003345676749 **false** (нет 128)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/FFladW/1

Comment: а может одна цифра присутствовать несколько раз?

Comment: [tag:регулярные-выражения] - подробнее..., прочитайте пример как задать хороший вопрос.

Comment: одна цифра может присутствовать несколько раз

Comment: @tocic спасибо, это подходит.
А в случае с буквами пришлось бы перечислять все буквы? Может есть еще варианты?

Comment: Да, перечислять все буквы. Лично я не знаю лучше вариантов (с помощью регулярок).